# Question on the relationship of a quantity and its value modulo n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is it correct to say that if there are 13 chameleons, then there are $1\pmod 3$ chameleons?

If so, why?

Comment: I'm okay with someone saying it that way, but we say a lot of things in abbreviated form when the context is clear.  I don't know how to tackle the "why" part of your query, except that if we state matters in a way that others don't understand, the goal of communicating is poorly served.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sort of, and if you understand the statement is a one-directional implication.

$(1)\;$ There are $13$ chameleons, and $\quad 13 = 4\cdot 3 + 1 \equiv 1\pmod 3$.

$(2)\;$ Therefore, the number of chameleons, when divided by $3$, leaves a remainder of $1$, which I suspect is what the intended meaning of the notation used when concluding that there are $1\pmod 3$ chameleons.

Yes, $(1)\implies (2)$. The fact that there are 13 chameleons implies that there are $1 \pmod 3$ chameleons. So the statement you post is true.

But that is **not** to suggest that the converse is  necessarily true. For example, pick $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Then $x\in \{\cdots, -5, -2, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, \cdots\}$. So knowing that there are $x$ chameleons such that $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ does NOT imply that $x$ has to be $13$.

The better way to summarize the statement is as follows:

> If there are $13$ chameleons, then there are $13\equiv 1\pmod 3$ chameleons.

Comment: Thank you, why is my question being voted down?

Comment: I don't know why. I think a handful of users spend more time criticizing than they do contributing. But note that some users may be noting that you've asked a lot of questions without accepting/upvoting any answers you do get. At any rate, don't take the downvotes personally. I simply think it says more about the downvoters than it does about the question; none of them seem to have had enough backbone to at least comment as to why they've downvoted.

Comment: Although not a downvoter, I did vote to close and left a comment.  Perhaps the Question is intentionally about omitting context; saying $1 \pmod{13}$ is itself an "abuse of notation" in the mathematical world, where "mod" denotes a relationship between integers rather than an intrinsic function or value.  Perhaps a good Answer would have been to suggest using "remainder" rather than "modulo" to express the thought.

Comment: Good comment, @hardmath. I edited my answer a bit to suggest that the notation $1\pmod 3$ is not the optimal way to express what I suspect is intended by its use. Thank you for chiming in! (BTW, I've never had reason, here or elsewhere, to reference you in my comment above. You are a consistently a respectful commenter, reviewer, and answerer, and clearly put a lot of thought into all your MSE/meta contributions.)